# Can you do smart types in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, types

Let's say I have in interface like this:

```js
export interface Promotion {
  title: string;
  image?: string;
  description?: string;
  startDate?: string;
  endDate?: string;
  type: 'discountWithImage' | 'discount' | 'countdown';
}
```

Now my questions is, since I now for sure that if the key `type` is equal to `'countdown'` then the endDate and the startDate will not be undefined. Is there a way to do it in typescript? so something like:

```js
export interface Promotion {
  title: string;
  image?: string;
  description?: string;
  startDate?: string;
  endDate: Promotion.type === 'countdown' ? string : undefined;
  type: 'discountWithImage' | 'discount' | 'countdown';
}
```

example to explain on playground [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgewLYOASwQOwCrmgXigHIATNAZwGMEBXTYAdTWAAsBJJAQwHMIioAPsTJVa9fkKLU6wEggDumIgG4AUKogAPMAjjAoaehDgAzTpWjxkqDJgA82KFuARMJcrEQp0WXJAB8UADeqlBQ6MAANhAAXFDkwHCG3GphaFy8APxxCUmYKaFQJBBUSWA%20mNnxicmp1Zx6ACKcLlW5tYWuJM0ucY7OXR5SYrIKSlCZ1XncUHF0xSaGECR1oJB9agC%206tSYCVAIAEYAVhCUwACMcVbetnacmCCBhEFhAPRvUAASxtBsUPJaJESFBMKgoJE0ABraDABBFeE3GxYOzDGRyRREfyFCLROJEIgAGk6bh6sWIRJxeHx0noGKUqm2ql2%20yOp3OACZrl5kfYHk8oC8oB9vr8oP9ATRgaDwZCYeF4XJPNYKqiRLTgFiccw8RTiWE1uTSBQNURGeo0CYABRss6XAB0hsF%20EIaLpYyIAEpgoVbecLvaumThZ8fnBYSxYXgoCZdE5SS1oOQWECQYdoFhIiApslzapLTaTnaOY7oy7XeqRl6fWE-Q6g4mQ6Lw%20FI%20Fo7G4PHuo3k6moOmDpgs1B5hBFphloygA)

Comment: You can do this with a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) - `Promotion` is either something with `type: 'discountWithImage' | 'discount'` and no end date, or something with `type: 'countdown'` and an end date.

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with a [generic type parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html). Think of it like and argument that you pass into your type.

```
type PromotionType = 'discountWithImage' | 'discount' | 'countdown';

export interface Promotion<T extends PromotionType> {
  title: string;
  image?: string;
  description?: string;
  startDate?: string;
  endDate: T extends 'countdown' ? string : undefined;
  type: T;
}
```

You would use it like so:

```
declare const testA: Promotion<'discount'>
const endDateA = testA.endDate // undefined

declare const testB: Promotion<'countdown'>
const endDateB = testB.endDate // string
```

You can even use a generic function to pass that type parameter for you:

```
function getPromotion<T extends PromotionType>(type: T): Promotion<T> {
  return {} as Promotion<T> // Not a real implementation
}

const resultA = getPromotion('discount').endDate // undefined
const resultB = getPromotion('countdown').endDate // string
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=18&ssc=1&pln=25&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgewLYOASwQOwCrmgXigHIATNAZwGMEBXTYAdTWAAsBJJAQwHMIioAPsTJVa9fkKLU6wEggDumIgG4AUKogAPMAjjAoaehDgAzTpWjxkqDJgA82KFuARMJcrEQp0WXJAB8UADeqlBQ6MAANhAAXFDkwHCG3GphaFy8APxxCUmYKaFQJBBUSWA+mNnxicmp1Zx6ACKcLlW5tYWuJM0ucY7OXR5SYrIKSlCZ1XncUHF0xSaGECR1oJB9agC+6sWUkQ3Q1JgJ4SXAAIJxVt62dqQU0uL+qkcnXT0Q51CELgnnAHTvFrQAD0IKg8wgi0wyx2ED2Bygr30v2AACErl4bFg7o9RooiM9kU43B80d9Tgk0YDScCoGCpsl1AyaORoPJmCwoJwoLwYUlKFATHRKBVVMLMKLbLyIMBrtj7P1NC43B55RU-BB-AAKNaxKDYACUmOsFQcgRCYTgspocEwwU23LVWLN2ECDIAcqhuVBrZxIgYkGBokhXMAWrZVNsXlgTtbyDRIhcKbw5S7bNr7qIZERDTTunSWW4oUsSDHjvp44n0SnZeqM8MZHICXmgS56eD2vlVEA)

---

Or you could define a [discriminated union](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/discriminated-unions) with the a slightly different interface depending on the value of `type`.

```
// One interface for common values that all promotions share
export interface PromotionCommon {
  title: string;
  image?: string;
  description?: string;
  startDate?: string;
}

// The discount promotion type has no end date and discount type.
export interface PromotionDiscount extends PromotionCommon {
  endDate: undefined;
  type: 'discountWithImage' | 'discount';
}

// The countdown promotion type has an end date and a countdown type.
export interface PromotionCountdown extends PromotionCommon {
  endDate: string;
  type: 'countdown';
}

// The final Promotion type can be either a discount or a countdown
type Promotion = PromotionDiscount | PromotionCountdown


declare const promotion: Promotion // pretend we have a promotion of unknown promotion type
if (promotion.type === 'countdown') {
  const endDate = promotion.endDate // type: string
} else {
  const endDate = promotion.endDate // type: undefined
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=25&pc=2#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgewLYOASwQOygXloldLAETQGcBjBAV02CgB99lUNMBhGugEwQHdMAKEEQAHmARx6aOhDgAzAIYVo8FkQ7IU2AN6CoUdMAA2EAFxQywODIDmAbn1Q0SRbYgB+C1ZuYHT7ghKGzANL0trO0cDK0UpYkVgT29Iv0cAX2ExCSlnWQVlVQJWEnIqWnoxJMxuMmZCNk4kbSg9AwgahKSLWkD5GQhuaMNwcygAcm4yrmAAdTRgAAsASVd3ccYJqcoZ8Yys8UlpfKUVepLNCt4BKCqO2vONJpa2287EsZ8op1BIC3Hyjx+Jg9oJMoJAhRjHFoFRMFYoGBihoLGoGlgoAB6TGIuAdarcKB8aCLRQAN2gilx6jYUAQ8igtAA1phgdT0dhfhBBGgGQAKJE0rAAOi5uBweABM2uIIAlK0nHCEfcutA8IKOcKVR8sTiuSlfLYwbdjGRoK8lZV3klcOyLlrrdBsSM-oyahB+phBmCgA)

Comment: This is close to what I am looking for, but the idea would be also that the type should not be defined but to be inferred something the would infer based on an if statement. Like that if I check for `object.type === 'discount'` then inside the if statement the `endDate` not be defined

Comment: Posted a playground link

Comment: See my update, which handles this in a different way.

Comment: I recommend the union approach as it is easier to refine/guard a variable just by looking at the `type`.